# Quartz.net for scheduling jobs on different server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, quartz.net

I want to create a web app and host on a server (say server A). We also want to create some jobs (windows services or C# console apps) and put them on server B.

I know that i can use task scheduler to schedule the jobs on Server B but my aim is to manage the jobs from server A via the web app (say admin panel). I mean that i should be able to see if the job is running, stop when required and start when required. should also be able to see the next run time etc..

I have seen Quartz.net but dont really understand how this can be achieved via Quartz. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz.Net is a powerfull scheduling lib.

Quartz.Net has a persistence layer in order to save your jobs/triggers/calendars in a DataBase and recover from crashes.

In order to monitor your job, you can add [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and monitor your QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS Table. Any changes in this table will be notified. Thus if a Job is added (start) or removed (endend) from QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS table, you will know it.